# How to increase FPS in Android Game?

Tags: android, multithreading, optimization, frame-rate

I am making an Android Game in which i am only getting in and around 20 FPS. This is the Thread Class i am using:

```
public class MainThread extends Thread 
    {   
        private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();

// desired fps
private final static int    MAX_FPS = 50;   
// maximum number of frames to be skipped
private final static int    MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;    
// the frame period
private final static int    FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;

// Stuff for stats */
private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");  // 2 dp
// we'll be reading the stats every second
private final static int    STAT_INTERVAL = 1000; //ms
// the average will be calculated by storing 
// the last n FPSs
private final static int    FPS_HISTORY_NR = 10;
// last time the status was stored
private long lastStatusStore = 0;
// the status time counter
private long statusIntervalTimer    = 0l;
// number of frames skipped since the game started
private long totalFramesSkipped         = 0l;
// number of frames skipped in a store cycle (1 sec)
private long framesSkippedPerStatCycle  = 0l;

// number of rendered frames in an interval
private int frameCountPerStatCycle = 0;
private long totalFrameCount = 0l;
// the last FPS values
private double  fpsStore[];
// the number of times the stat has been read
private long    statsCount = 0;
// the average FPS since the game started
private double  averageFps = 0.0;

// Surface holder that can access the physical surface
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
// The actual view that handles inputs
// and draws to the surface
private PlayView playView;
// flag to hold game state 
private boolean running;

public void setRunning(boolean running)
{
    this.running = running;
}

public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, PlayView playView)
{
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.playView = playView;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
    // initialise timing elements for stat gathering
    initTimingElements();

    long beginTime;     // the time when the cycle begun
    long timeDiff;      // the time it took for the cycle to execute
    int sleepTime;      // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
    int framesSkipped;  // number of frames being skipped 

    sleepTime = 0;

    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
        // in the surface
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            synchronized (surfaceHolder) 
            {
                beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                framesSkipped = 0;  // resetting the frames skipped
                // update game state 
                this.playView.update();
                // render state to the screen
                // draws the canvas on the panel
                this.playView.render(canvas);               
                // calculate how long did the cycle take
                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                // calculate sleep time
                sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                    // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
                    try {
                        // send the thread to sleep for a short period
                        // very useful for battery saving
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);    
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }

                while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) 
                {
                    // we need to catch up
                    this.playView.update(); // update without rendering
                    sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;  // add frame period to check if in next frame
                    framesSkipped++;
                }

                if (framesSkipped > 0) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Skipped:" + framesSkipped);
                }

                // for statistics
                framesSkippedPerStatCycle += framesSkipped;
                // calling the routine to store the gathered statistics
                storeStats();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
            // an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null) 
            {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }   // end finally
    }
}


private void storeStats()
{
    frameCountPerStatCycle++;
    totalFrameCount++;

    // check the actual time
    statusIntervalTimer += (System.currentTimeMillis() - statusIntervalTimer);

    if (statusIntervalTimer >= lastStatusStore + STAT_INTERVAL) {
        // calculate the actual frames pers status check interval
        double actualFps = (double)(frameCountPerStatCycle / (STAT_INTERVAL / 1000));

        //stores the latest fps in the array
        fpsStore[(int) statsCount % FPS_HISTORY_NR] = actualFps;

        // increase the number of times statistics was calculated
        statsCount++;

        double totalFps = 0.0;
        // sum up the stored fps values
        for (int i = 0; i < FPS_HISTORY_NR; i++) {
            totalFps += fpsStore[i];
        }

        // obtain the average
        if (statsCount < FPS_HISTORY_NR) {
            // in case of the first 10 triggers
            averageFps = totalFps / statsCount;
        } else {
            averageFps = totalFps / FPS_HISTORY_NR;
        }
        // saving the number of total frames skipped
        totalFramesSkipped += framesSkippedPerStatCycle;
        // resetting the counters after a status record (1 sec)
        framesSkippedPerStatCycle = 0;
        statusIntervalTimer = 0;
        frameCountPerStatCycle = 0;

        statusIntervalTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lastStatusStore = statusIntervalTimer;
        //          Log.d(TAG, "Average FPS:" + df.format(averageFps));
        playView.setAvgFps("FPS: " + df.format(averageFps));
    }
}

private void initTimingElements()
{
    // initialise timing elements
    fpsStore = new double[FPS_HISTORY_NR];
    for (int i = 0; i < FPS_HISTORY_NR; i++) {
        fpsStore[i] = 0.0;
    }

    Log.d(TAG + ".initTimingElements()", "Timing elements for stats initialised");


}

}
```

Despite my best efforts to improve the FPS, it is not improving. All suggestion for optimizing this code are welcome.

Comment: I see nothing obvious here. It would be interesting to know what happens in PlayView.

Comment: In PlayView, i am drawing the objects in render() and updating their position and movement in update().

Comment: This is maybe where you can gain some cpu time. Rendering can be awfully consuming.